# Multiple Checkbox

Tags: plugins

I cannot save & display the checkbox state on page update.

```
function checkbox(){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $field_id = $custom["field_id"];
    echo "hola".$field_id[0];

    $blogusers = get_users( );  
    foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
        ?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="field_id[]" value="<?php echo $user->ID ;?>" <?php checked( in_array( absint( $user->ID ),$portfolio_cats ),true ); ?>/>
    <label><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></label><br>

<?php
    }
}

// Save Meta Details
add_action('save_post', 'save_detail');

function save_detail(){
    global $post;
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post->ID;
    }


    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_id', $data);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing several bad things, the main one is tha you are not getting the data from the checkboxes and that you are passing an undefined variable `$data` to `update_post_meta` function. You could start reading the PHP manual, maybe starting with [Variables From External Sources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) and [dealing with forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php).

Comment: The error of $ data is for changes to test possible solutions and to eliminate not remove fine as below is corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you're doing several things wrong, namely mismatching field names & undefined variables:

```
function checkbox(){
    global $post;

    if ( ! is_array( $user_ids = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'user_ids', true ) ) )
        $user_ids = array();

    $users = get_users();    
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        ?>

<input id="user_field_<?php echo $user->ID ?>" type="checkbox" name="user_ids[]" value="<?php echo $user->ID ?>" <?php checked( in_array( $user->ID, $user_ids ) ) ?> /> 
<label for="user_field_<?php echo $user->ID ?>"><?php echo $user->display_name ?></label><br />
        <?php
    }

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="user_ids[]" value="0" />';
}

/**
 * Handler for saving our checkbox states.
 * 
 * @param   int $post_id    The current post being saved.
 */
function save_detail( $post_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['user_ids'] ) ) {
        $user_ids = array_map( 'absint', ( array ) $_POST['user_ids'] );
        $user_ids = array_filter( $user_ids );

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'user_ids', $user_ids );
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_detail' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and spent several days with the problem and could not see the solution

Comment: If I wanted to show the value of the checkbox on the single page, would have to do something special? @thedeadmedic

Comment: You can use the same code from `checkbox()`